# When to choose mouseover() and hover() function?

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

What are the differences between jQuery `.mouseover()` and `.hover()` functions? If they are totally same why jQuery uses both?

Comment: This is not duplicate question. your provided link has mouseover and mouseenter events but mine is mouseover and hover events.

Comment: they are different in the same as mouseover nad mouseleave and the accepted answer below is not accurate... the hover function adds a mouseenter and mouseleve events not mouseover and mouseout events

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cZb5b/1/ move the mouse from the `el` element to `child` and check the console

Comment: @ArunPJohny please re-read, that's saying mouseenter and mouseleave not mouseover and mouseout.

Comment: also with hover - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cZb5b/2/ if you can analyze the console, you can find the difference...

Answer (score 130, accepted):

## From the official jQuery documentation

- [`.mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)
  Bind an event handler to the "mouseover" JavaScript event, or trigger
  that event on an element.

---

- [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)   Bind one or two handlers
  to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer
  *enters* and *leaves* the elements.

  Calling `$(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)` is shorthand for: 
  `$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);`

---

- [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

  Bind an event handler to be fired when the mouse enters an element,
  or trigger that handler on an element.

  `mouseover` fires when the pointer moves into the child element as
  well, while `mouseenter` fires only when the pointer moves into the
  bound element.

---

## What this means

Because of this, `.mouseover()` is *not* the same as `.hover()`, for the same reason `.mouseover()` is *not* the same as `.mouseenter()`.

```
$('selector').mouseover(over_function) // may fire multiple times

// enter and exit functions only called once per element per entry and exit
$('selector').hover(enter_function, exit_function)
```

Answer (score 33):

`.hover()` function accepts two function arguments, one for `mouseenter` event and one for `mouseleave` event.

Comment: this is a great point in terms of the differences between the two functions mentioned in the question title, Thanks! check out the link below on w3schools for how .hover() works: 
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp

Answer (score 9):

You can try it out http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/ on the jQuery doc page. It's a nice little, interactive demo that makes it very clear and you can actually see for yourself.

In short, you'll notice that a mouse over event occurs on an element when you are over it - coming from either its child OR parent element, but a mouse enter event only occurs when the mouse moves from the parent element to the element.

Answer (score 2):

From the offical docs: (http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

> The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element.

Answer (score 2):

As you can read at http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

> The mouseenter JavaScript event is proprietary to Internet Explorer.
>   Because of the event's general utility, jQuery simulates this event so
>   that it can be used regardless of browser. This event is sent to an
>   element when the mouse pointer enters the element. Any HTML element
>   can receive this event.