# Change DIV content on mouse-over

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I have an existing script i've been using for content display. Currently it works when you click on a link. Is it possible to modify it to work on mouse-over instead of a click.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfq2L/):

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="1"><div class="block"></div></a>
<a href="#" id="2"><div class="block"></div></a>
<a href="#" id="3"><div class="block"></div></a>

<div class="content"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#1').click(); 
});

$('#1').click(function() {
  $('.content').html('This is a text example 1');
});

$('#2').click(function() {
  $('.content').html('This is a text example 2');
});

$('#3').click(function() {
  $('.content').html('This is a text example 3');
});
```

Comment: Change `click` to `mouseover`?

Comment: Thanks @FarhadJabiyev, now i feel stupid. That was easy. But a google search has confused me. When do we use .mouseover and .hover ?

Comment: `.hover()` function accepts two function arguments, one for `mouseenter` event and one for `mouseleave` event.

Comment: Thanks! @FarhadJabiyev I'll read up more on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change `click()` to `mouseover();`.

You can also use `mouseenter()`. See the link for more explanation ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover)).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vfq2L/1/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#1').mouseover(); 
});

$('#1').mouseover(function() {
  $('.content').html('This is a text example 1');
});

$('#2').mouseover(function() {
  $('.content').html('This is a text example 2');
});

$('#3').mouseover(function() {
  $('.content').html('This is a text example 3');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Replace `click()` with [`mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#1').click(); 
 });

 $('#1').mouseover(function() {
  $('.content').html('This is a text example 1');
});

$('#2').mouseover(function() {
  $('.content').html('This is a text example 2');
 });
 $('#3').mouseover(function() {
  $('.content').html('This is a text example 3');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace **click()** with **mouseover()**:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#1').mouseover(); 
});

$('#1').mouseover(function() {
$('.content').html('This is a text example 1');
});

$('#2').mouseover(function() {
$('.content').html('This is a text example 2');
});

$('#3').mouseover(function() {
$('.content').html('This is a text example 3');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just replace .click() with .hover() or .mouseover() ([See the difference between hover and mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589420/when-to-choose-mouseover-and-hover-function)):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#1').click(); 
});

$('#1').hover(function() {
  $('.content').html('This is a text example 1');
});

$('#2').hover(function() {
  $('.content').html('This is a text example 2');
});

$('#3').hover(function() {
  $('.content').html('This is a text example 3');
});
```

Here you can see how it works on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZF6dk/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some deprecated functions issue and shows error if use latest version of jQuery (SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead)

Change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#1, #2, #3').mouseover(function(evt) {
        $('.content').html('This is a text example' + evt.currentTarget.id);
    });
});
```