# Hovering Images on the Left then the Images on the Right will change using Slide Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

Good day. I'm doing some design like this in my banner(saksoff5th.com) I use slideToggle instead. When I hover images on the left the banner images on the right will change. But I'm having difficulties in hovering the images on the right. Like when I hover images on the left, the images on the right is wrong. I don't have any idea also how can I make my images appears properly on the right part. They are all in one vertical. I want it to work like if I hover the first image on the left, the first image on the right will appear. When I hover the second image on the right, the second image will appear and the first image will hide etc.

Here is my jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/deanilvincent/7Lgks56u/2/) *Note: It's now working! Thanks for the help :D*

Help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

**My HTML Tags:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="left-panel">
        <ul>
            <li class="first-left"><a href="#"><img src="images/1st.png" /></a></li>
            <li class="second-left"><a href="#"><img src="images/2nd.png" /></a></li>
            <li class="third-left"><a href="#"><img src="images/3rd.png" /></a></li>
            <li class="fourth-left"><a href="#"><img src="images/4th.png" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="right-panel">
        <ul>
        <li class="first-right"><a href="#"><img src="images/banner1.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li class="second-right"><a href="#"><img src="images/banner2.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li class="third-right"><a href="#"><img src="images/banner3.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li class="fourth-right"><a href="#"><img src="images/banner4.jpg" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My Javascript/Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#left-panel ul li.first-left").mouseover(function(){
            $("#right-panel ul li.first-right").slideToggle("Fast");
        });

        $("#left-panel ul li.second-left").mouseover(function(){
            $("#right-panel ul li.second-right").slideToggle("Fast");
        });

        $("#left-panel ul li.third-left").mouseover(function(){
            $("#right-panel ul li.third-right").slideToggle("Fast");
        });

        $("#left-panel ul li.fourth-left").mouseover(function(){
            $("#right-panel ul li.fourth-right").slideToggle("Fast");
        });
    });
```

**My CSS:**

```
.container{
        width:1200px;
        margin:0px auto;
    }
    #left-panel{
        width:20%;
        float:left;
    }
    #left-panel ul li a:hover{
        background-color:#eeeeee;
    }
    #left-panel ul li{
        list-style-type:none;
    }
    #right-panel ul li{
        list-style-type:none;
    }
    #right-panel{
        width:80%;
        float:left;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include jQuery in the fiddle (from the menu on the left)

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/7Lgks56u/5/

```
     //Hide all except the first
    $("#right-panel ul li").not("#right-panel ul li.first-right").stop().slideUp("Fast");


    $("#left-panel ul li.first-left").mouseover(function(){
        //Hide all
        $("#right-panel ul li").stop().slideUp("Fast");
        //Show the first 
        $("#right-panel ul li.first-right").stop().slideDown("Fast");
    }); 

//etc...
```

Comment: Ahhh Thanks sir for the correction! :D So sir! I think "hover" is better than mouse over. Take a look of it.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! Sir I have a question, what is the differences of hover and mouseover in jquery?

Comment: in your case, it doesn't matter if you use hover or mouseover. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589420/when-to-choose-mouseover-and-hover-function

Comment: Thank you so much sir Miro! God bless and take care! :D

Answer (score 1):

i think your code in JSFiddle is not working because you didn't import jquery, it is just a detail. Wherever, if you want to show the correct right image when you enter the mouse over the left image and *only that image*, you have to write exactly that, for example, if you enter the mouse over the second left image, so the second right image will *slidetoggle* and the others will be **hide**, that is the idea, here is ugly snippet but it works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#left-panel ul li.first-left").mouseover(function(){
    if (!$("#right-panel ul li.first-right").is(":visible")) 
      $("#right-panel ul li.first-right").slideToggle("Fast");
    $("#right-panel ul li.second-right").hide();
    $("#right-panel ul li.third-right").hide();
    $("#right-panel ul li.fourth-right").hide();
  });

  $("#left-panel ul li.second-left").mouseover(function(){
    if (!$("#right-panel ul li.second-right").is(":visible")) 
      $("#right-panel ul li.second-right").slideToggle("Fast");
    $("#right-panel ul li.first-right").hide();
    $("#right-panel ul li.third-right").hide();
    $("#right-panel ul li.fourth-right").hide();
  });

  $("#left-panel ul li.third-left").mouseover(function(){
    if (!$("#right-panel ul li.third-right").is(":visible")) 
      $("#right-panel ul li.third-right").slideToggle("Fast");
    $("#right-panel ul li.first-right").hide();
    $("#right-panel ul li.second-right").hide();
    $("#right-panel ul li.fourth-right").hide();
  });

  $("#left-panel ul li.fourth-left").mouseover(function(){
    if (!$("#right-panel ul li.fourth-right").is(":visible"))
      $("#right-panel ul li.fourth-right").slideToggle("Fast");
    $("#right-panel ul li.first-right").hide();
    $("#right-panel ul li.second-right").hide();
    $("#right-panel ul li.third-right").hide();
  });
});
```

and you have to add this on the stylesheet:

```
#right-panel li {
  display: none;
}

#right-panel li:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
}
```

this is because, initially the first image will be displayed by default.

Comment: No worries, i'm glad for that :)

Comment: Sir I mean "Not" haha typographically error on my own. Sorry Sir.