# Detecting whether mouse is in an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page that uses jQuery. My page looks something like this:

```
<div id="page">
  <!-- Stuff here -->
  <div id="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col"><!-- stuff --></div>
      <div class="col"><!-- stuff --></div>
      <div class="col"><!-- stuff --></div>
      <div class="col"><!-- stuff --></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col"><!-- stuff --></div>
      <div class="col"><!-- stuff --></div>
      <div class="col"><!-- stuff --></div>      
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Stuff here -->
</div>

<div id="note" style="display:none;">
  <!-- stuff here -->
</div>

var noteTimeout = null;
var note = $('#note');
$(".row")
  .mouseover(function () {
    var col = $(this).find('.col:last');
    var p = col.position();

    note.css({zIndex:1000, top: p.top, left: (p.left + col.width() - note.width()/2) });
    note.show();
          })
  .mouseout(function (e) {
    if (noteTimeout != null) {
      clearTimeout(noteTimeout);
    }
    noteTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
      note.fadeOut(150);
    }, 250);
  })
;
```

Basically, when a user hovers over a row, I'm trying to show a note in the last column of the row. If a user moves to another row, the note moves to that row. However, if the user's mouse is outside of the "content" area, I want to hide the note after 250 milliseconds. The last requirement is causing me problems.

As it is, the note disappears after 250 milliseconds if I change rows. However, if I remove the timeout, the note flickers if a user moves their mouse over it.

Comment: That's quite a bit of code - may I suggest creating a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so we some code to work with and debug.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `.hover` for the element (in this case an array of elements) which detects as the mouse enters and leaves. It's an expansion of the functionality of `.mouseenter()` & `.mouseleave()`.

This is will make it so that whilst the mouse is over the element it will do something rather than `.mouseover` which simply triggers an event.

This is explained further by Navin Rauniyar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589420/when-to-choose-mouseover-and-hover-function)