# .on mouseover and eventListener proper placement

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onmouseover

I created an etch-a-sketch type of program so that when a user enters a height, width, and select a color choice, they are able to draw on the provided grid below. I am having troubles with the drawing part.  I included a link to my code via codepen ... Online 37, I created a mouseover event but I can't figure out why it won't work. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
   $("#pixelCanvas td").on("mouseover",  function(){
   var colorPicker = $("#colorPicker").val();
   $( this ).css("background-color",colorPicker );
   });

  https://codepen.io/unicorn1/pen/JpVmZV
```

Comment: Please include the code from your external source in the question here on Stack Overflow. Also explain what is meant be "won't work". See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: You might take a look at https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/106380/what-is-the-difference-between-a-mouseover-and-a-hoverover/106382

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when to choose mouseover() and hover() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589420/when-to-choose-mouseover-and-hover-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#pixelCanvas").on("mouseover", "td", function(){
  var colorPicker = $("#colorPicker").val();
  $(this).css("background-color", colorPicker);
});
```

Your `td` are being dynamically genererated, your `#pixelCanvas` exists from start, so you want to put an `eventListener` on the `#pixelCanvas`, but you only want it to react if a `td` is actually clicked. Since the `#pixelCanvas` existed from the start it will know if there happened something inside of it's container, while i generated `td` wouldn't know that it was supposed to have an `eventListener`

Answer (score -1):

I think this discussion shows you the main differences between mouseover and hover.
Here is the link to it ([when to choose mouseover() and hover() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589420/when-to-choose-mouseover-and-hover-function)

Comment: [When someone goes on Stack Overflow, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).