# on hover or on click run function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have the script work whether you are hovering or clicking but it seems to only work on click.

```
  // Adding an active class
  $('.donation-level-input-container label').on('click hover', function(e){
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('for');

    $('.donation-level-user-entered').removeClass('active');

    $('.donation-level-input-container label').each(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
    });

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.donation-level-user-entered input').val('')
  });

  $('.donation-level-user-entered input').on('focus', function(e) {
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('for');

    $('.donation-level-input-container label').each(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
    });

    $('.donation-level-user-entered').addClass('active');
  });
  });
  });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `mouseover` not `hover`.

Comment: please share the html code also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `mouseover` instead `hover`. 
Please refer this link for more details [when to choose mouseover() and hover() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589420/when-to-choose-mouseover-and-hover-function)

Below is your code:

```
// Adding an active class
  $('.donation-level-input-container label').on('click mouseover', function(e){
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('for');

    $('.donation-level-user-entered').removeClass('active');

    $('.donation-level-input-container label').each(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
    });

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.donation-level-user-entered input').val('')
  });

  $('.donation-level-user-entered input').on('focus', function(e) {
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('for');

    $('.donation-level-input-container label').each(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
    });

    $('.donation-level-user-entered').addClass('active');
  });
  });
  });
```